# How to bind a color value to two colors and a percentage?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors

Quite hard to summarize the question...

Let's say I have two `Color` object in my XAML resources, `Start` and `End`.

I also have a Rectangle, and I want his `Fill` property to be binded to a converter, which would take 3 parameters: 2 Colors and a number between 0 and 1.

The converter would return a Color being... how to say that... the weighted median of the two Color it retrieved as parameters.

For example, if it receives a full red, a full blue and the value 0.75, it would return a blue-ish purple:
[image]

I fall short of ideas on how to do that. Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MultiBinding and IMultiConverter. With this, you can bind as many properties as you need using a converter to create the color.

Have a look here:
http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html

Answer (score 1):

This should provide the fading logic :

```
private System.Windows.Media.Color GetFadedColor(System.Windows.Media.Color start, System.Windows.Media.Color end, double ratio)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ratio >= 0 && ratio <= 1);
        return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb((byte)(start.A + (ratio * (end.A - start.A))), (byte)(start.R + (ratio * (end.R - start.R))), (byte)(start.G + (ratio * (end.G - start.G))), (byte)(start.B + (ratio * (end.B - start.B))));
    }
```